# When unpacking a dictionary to pass as keyword arguments, how can I map a key to a differently named keyword argument?

Tags: python, arguments, keyword-argument

Let's say I have some code:

```
def test(a, b, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

l = {'a': 0, 'c': 1, 'foo': 2, 'bar': 3}
```

What I want to do is to pass the unpacked dictionary into the function, but map its key `c` to parameter `b`, while preserving any other keys that do not directly correspond to a parameter in kwargs, so the function should output `{'foo': 2, 'bar': 3}`. If I do `test(b=l['c'], **l)`, the key `c` remains in kwargs, and output looks like this: `{'foo': 2, 'bar': 3, 'c': 1}`. `test(**l)`, obviously, crashes with an error - `test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'`.

How is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove key `c` and add `b`:

```
def test(a, b, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

l = {'a': 0, 'c': 1, 'foo': 2, 'bar': 3}

l2 = l.copy()
l2['b'] = l2['c']
del l2['c']

test(**l2)
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 2, 'bar': 3}
```

https://repl.it/NXd2/0

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not possible. Just manipulate your dictionary before passing it in to the call:

```
b = l.pop('c')
test(b=b, **l)
```

or

```
l['b'] = l.pop('c')
test(**l)
```

or

```
test(**{'b' if k == 'c' else k: v for k, v in l.items()})
```

all of which pass in a dictionary to the `**` syntax that does not have a `c` key in it.

Answer (score 1):

For a more sophisticated cases when there would be a need to map/adjust multiple keys without mutating the initial input dictionary - consider using ***decorators***:

```
import functools

def map_keys_decorator():
    def decorate(func):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def mapped_test(*args, **kwargs):
            kwargs = dict(kwargs)
            kwargs['b'] = kwargs.pop('c')   # here you can add another additonal logic
            return func(**kwargs)
        return mapped_test

    return decorate

@map_keys_decorator()
def test(a, b, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

l = {'a': 0, 'c': 1, 'foo': 2, 'bar': 3}
test(**l)    # {'foo': 2, 'bar': 3}

print(l)     # {'foo': 2, 'bar': 3, 'c': 1, 'a': 0}
```

Comment: What's the point of doing `kwargs = dict(kwargs)`? Can kwargs _not_ be a dict?

Comment: @Dariush, I've wrote in my title *without mutating the initial input dictionary*, `kwargs = dict(kwargs)` will copy the passed dictionary, the initial dictionary remains unchanged. Your case with single key substitution is simple, my approach is for a more sophisticated cases